# How can I click on elements using Selenium Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to generalize much as possible a code in order to scrape eBay website.
I am now stuck in this situation:

this is the following URL where I start:

```
https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iphone+12&_oac=1
```

I want to click on the "More filters" button and then select specifically the 'Brand' option and get the list of the available brands.

This is what I was able to do till now:

```
url = 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iphone+12&_oac=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('s0-14-11-0-1-2-6-2').click()
```

after click() the sub panel is open and I get what I need to change:

```
<div role="tab" class="x-overlay-aspect " data-aspecttitle="aspect-Brand" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="refineOverlay-subPanel" id="c3-mainPanel-Brand"><span class="x-overlay-aspect__label">Brand</span><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="x-overlay-aspect__check-icon svg-icon icon-check" role="img" aria-label="Filter applied"><use xlink:href="#svg-icon-check"></use></svg></div>
```

if I select manually (i.e. clicking with the cursor) on 'Brand' here is what I get back:

```
<div role="tab" class="x-overlay-aspect active" tabindex="0" data-aspecttitle="aspect-Brand" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="refineOverlay-subPanel" id="c3-mainPanel-Brand"><span class="x-overlay-aspect__label">Brand</span><svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="x-overlay-aspect__check-icon svg-icon icon-check" role="img" aria-label="Filter applied"><use xlink:href="#svg-icon-check"></use></svg></div>
```

Unfortunately, I barely know Javascript so, althought there are other similar posts, I don't know how to keep going from here in order to get finally the information I need.

I hope you can help and I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click **More filters** and then to click on **Brand** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iphone+12&_oac=1")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'More filters')]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Brand']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: brand]